# Can I add an exception to re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

I currently have a python program that uses regular expressions to make a list of all the email addresses in a document and put them each on their own line in a new document. Works like this:

```
with open (self.originalEntry.get(), 'r') as doc:
    text = doc.read()
match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
with open (self.namesEntry.get(), 'a') as pi:
    for i in match:   
        i = str(i)
        pi.write(i+ '\n')
```

I want to change it to make a list of every email address *except* those from a given domain (i.e. anyone@thiswebsite.com.) I've been looking everything I can find about RE operators on python's site and can't find a way to build in an exception to the `re.findall` operator. Is it possible to write an expression to find all email addresses minus ones from a certain domain this way, or should I do something else?

Comment: why not just get a list of results, and then remove those from the list?

Comment: You can use a "negative lookahead" - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not just not write the email addresses with that domain to `self.namesEntry.get()`?

```
with open (self.originalEntry.get(), 'r') as doc:
    text = doc.read()
match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
with open (self.namesEntry.get(), 'a') as pi:
    for i in match:   
        i = str(i)
        if 'thiswebsite' not in i:
            pi.write(i+ '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "negative lookahead" - `(?!)`:

```
[\w\.-]+@(?!thiswebsite\.com)[\w\.-]+
```

This causes the expression only to match if the contents of the `(?!)` does not match. Also, it doesn't consume any characters - so it allows the rest of the expression to work as before.

See working example: https://regex101.com/r/mkEN3E/1